# uwsgi + nginx: status 502 on heavy load

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I have this nginx + uwsgi  + django application which works pretty well.

But when load on server gets a bit heavier, I start getting these 502 errors on random requests.

Here's the relevant section of uwsgi.ini:

```
master = true
#more processes, more computing power
processes = 32
threads = 3
post-buffering = 1
# this one must match net.core.somaxconn
listen = 8000
```

I have this huge number of processes to handle larger numbers of simultaneous requests - and I even added some threads on top of that - but I must admit I expected the `listen` directive should handle that. In reality it seems 502 errors start happening the moment I exceed 32 * 3 simultaneous requests.

The way I understood it, listen should allow up to 8000 (in this case) of active connections, waiting to be served by the server, but it doesn't seem to have any serious effect.

uwsgi log clearly says this is active:

```
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 8000 connections
```

But I seem to be misunderstanding the effect of the setting.

Anyway, I'd just like to solve the 502, so I'm open for suggestions in any direction.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where under load, I start to get 502's back from uWSGI.

Long story short, check that you are on `HTTP/1.1`, that you are using `--http11-socket`, and that you are on `uWSGI=2.0.16` or later.

http/1.1 does a persistent connection by default. I found that 502's occur when the listen queue grows and connections start to get dropped. Have a look at my article for the whole story

https://wontonst.blogspot.com/2019/06/squishing-performance-bug-in.html